# Powerpoint VBA Select a Range of Slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

While there are many responses on how to set a range if you know the Indexes/Names, what I need is a way to select a range of slides without specifying each slide index or name.

I have a slide called "C2 Title" at the start of a section and a slide called "C2Approval" at the end of a section.  The amount of slides between the two will vary depending on if users add slides in the middle. I want to select all the slides in between the two regardless of how many slides are inserted.

I suspect there is a way to loop through the indexes to populate the array but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that.

UPDATE: Per request below here is what I've tried

```
Sub SelectSection()
Dim sIndex As Long
Dim eIndex As Long
Dim sArray() As Long
Dim sSlides As SlideRange


ActivePresentation.Slides("C2Title").Select
sIndex = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex

ActivePresentation.Slides("C2DirectionalApproval").Select
eIndex = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex

'This solution only gets the first/last slide of range
Set sSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(eIndex - 1, sIndex + 1))

'Problem is this assumes I've already selected Slides
sSlides = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
 ReDim myArray(1 To sSlides.count)
      For y = LBound(sArray) To UBound(myArray)
        sArray(y) = Slides(y).SlideIndex
      Next y



End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Please do share a bit more detail of what you have tried so far!

Comment: You could just enumerate the slides in the section and populate it. Here is some code around sections - http://skphub.com/2010/ppt001.htm

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  sSlides.count is just eindex-sindex-1. Are you trying to load the indexes of the slide range into an array?

Comment: I found the sslides code on several sites as a way to define all the slides in an array except I can't figure out how it is supposed to work. My goal is to select all slides between C2Title and C2Approval slides

Comment: @H_Thurber Do you really NEED to select all the slides?  If you can find the Index of the first and last slides, then probably all you need is a For x = FirstSlideIndex to LastSlideIndex [do stuff with Slide(x)] Next loop

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Steve Rindsberg that was a great idea and got it to work

```
Sub SelectSection()
Dim eIndex As Long 'Index of End of Selection of Slide
Dim lIndex As Long 'Index used to select slides in loop
Dim pIndex As Long 'Index used to determine paste spot

lIndex = ActivePresentation.Slides("C2Title").SlideIndex + 1
eIndex = ActivePresentation.Slides("C2Approval").SlideIndex
pIndex = ActivePresentation.Slides("C3Title").SlideIndex


ActivePresentation.Slides(lIndex).Select
Do While (ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex < eIndex)
'Copies the selected slide
ActivePresentation.Slides(lIndex).Copy
'Selects next slide in Chapter 3, pastes in copied slide and changes subtitle
ActivePresentation.Slides(pIndex).Select
pIndex = pIndex + 1
ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste Index:=pIndex
ActivePresentation.Slides(pIndex).Shapes("Subtitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Chapter 3: Information Systems Architecture"
'Selects next slide in presentation
ActivePresentation.Slides(lIndex).Select
lIndex = lIndex + 1
'Selects slide to copy
ActivePresentation.Slides(lIndex).Select
Loop

End Sub
```